# How can I change the colour of the blue links (Twitter Widget)?

Tags: twitter, widget

Here's the site: http://www.victoryfights.co.uk

Can only view on desktop currently.

Scroll down on the first page to see the embedded Twitter feed. I need to change the blue links to white.

Just that, nothing more. I've tried a bunch of CSS and nothing works.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can add custom style hope this helps
https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview/css

Comment: Read that already and all the obvious ones via google. Can't figure how to target what I need, the obvious code ideas don't seem to work.